# R - Comparing values in a vector to a single value (Using the apply family)

Tags: r

I Have this database (shortened)

```
> head(testDB,25)
 Civilite Age Enfants Region Recence Frequence_visite_site Mailing_Clic
1      Mlle  18     Non   Nord       5                     5          Oui
2      Mlle  18     Non    Sud       3                     5          Oui
3      Mlle  18     Non   Nord       3                     8          Non
4      Mlle  18     Non   Nord       7                     6          Non
5      Mlle  18     Non   Nord      10                     5          Non
6        Mr  18     Non   Nord       4                     8          Oui
7        Mr  19     Non    Sud       4                     7          Oui
8      Mlle  20     Non    Sud       4                     8          Oui
9      Mlle  20     Non    Sud       3                     4          Oui
10     Mlle  20     Non   Nord       9                     4          Oui
11     Mlle  20     Non   Nord       5                     7          Oui
12     Mlle  20     Non   Nord       3                     5          Non
13     Mlle  20     Non   Nord      12                     4          Non
14     Mlle  20     Non   Nord      15                     2          Non
15     Mlle  20     Non   Nord       9                     7          Non
16     Mlle  20     Non   Nord      18                     5          Non
17     Mlle  20     Non   Nord      16                     4          Non
18     Mlle  20     Non   Nord      12                     8          Non
19     Mlle  20     Non   Nord      11                     8          Non
20     Mlle  21     Non    Sud       4                     6          Oui
21     Mlle  21     Non    Sud      15                     8          Oui
22     Mlle  21     Non    Sud       4                     8          Oui
23     Mlle  21     Non    Sud       4                     2          Oui
24     Mlle  21     Non    Sud       6                     4          Oui
25       Mr  21     Non   Nord       4                     8          Oui
```

and these, my first center of classes:

```
> K1 = 4
CenterOfClasses = testDB[sample(1:nrow(testDB), K1, replace=FALSE), ]
CenterOfClasses
Civilite Age Enfants Region Recence Frequence_visite_site Mailing_Clic
Mlle     45     Non   Nord      11                     6          Non
Mr       37     Non   Nord      10                     7          Non
Mr       56     Non   Nord      14                     6          Non
Mlle     43     Non   Nord      11                     8          Non
```

I have a problem when trying to calculate the differences between a vector (being the individual records of testDB) and an element (being each of the elements of my center of classes).

These are my variables:

```
DVar = list()
VectClasses ##Vector
VectIndVar  ##Vector

VectClasses1 = CenterOfClasses[1,] etc
VectIndVar = testBD
```

This is the function I am trying to use

```
mapply(function(x, y){
  sum(identical(x,y))},
VectClasses[x,y],VectIndVar[,y])
```

This is what I want to do :

```
DVar[[nClass]][nVar]=sum(VectClasses[nClass,nVar] == VectIndVar[,nVar])
```

(compare the 1st column of my database to the value assigned to the first class for the first variable, and that for each variables and classes there might be)

I changed my approach to now compare each record of database to each row of the VectClasses

I have tried this :

```
xall = data.frame()
for (k in 1:nrow(VectClasses)) 
 {
   for (i in 1:nrow(VectIndVar))
   {
     xall[i,k] = sum(VectClasses[k,] == VectIndVar[i,])
    }
 }
```

It returns :

```
  > head(xall)
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  3  3  2  2
2  2  2  1  1
3  3  4  3  3
4  3  4  3  3
5  4  4  3  3
6  3  2  3  3
```

Now, I tried to cut the loops for and replace it with an apply-family function

```
xball = sapply(xball, function(i,k){sum(VectClasses[k,] == VectIndVar[i,])})
```

But it doesn't fill xball

I would like to avoid as much as possible to loop over the number of classes, or the number of variables.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible please?

Comment: can you dput your data?

Comment: I think `VectClasses[x,y],VectIndVar[,y])`  seems to be not correct.  Anyway, an example would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ivar <- VectIndVar[rep(1:nrow(VectIndVar), nrow(VectClasses)), ]
vclass <- VectClasses[rep(1:nrow(VectClasses), each = nrow(ivar) / K1), ]
xball <- matrix(rowSums(vclass == ivar), ncol = nrow(VectClasses))
```

This creates two new matrixes dynamically, in order to get two data.frames of the same size, thus making the equality test possible. (It was Rawr's idea)

And it takes about 80 times less time than the loops "for".